# Getting pointer to COM object in java

Tags: java, com, jna

I am looking at how to get a pointer to a COM object in Java so that I can pass the pointer on to another native DLL.

At the moment I have been using the JACOB Java COM bridge, however I do not notice anything about how to get a pointer to the actual COM object which I could pass to a native DLL function call.

I have previously used Java Native Access (JNA) rather than JNI for calling DLL functions and I have noticed that JNA now seems to have some stuff for working with COM. I have two related questions on this JNA COM support: How well does the COM support of JNA work, is it ready for use in projects? Is there any tutorial on using the JNA COM support as the documentation for the COM support is limited and I am not sure how I should be using it.

I guess there is a third question relating to JNA and COM, will it allow me to get a pointer to a COM object and then pass it to the native DLL C type function? I almost am guessing yes as the inheritence of the objects look like the COM stuff will work with making standard native DLL calls from JNA, I just want to clarify that.

Finally, while I have mainly asked about JNA as that is a possible solution I have found, I am open to other possibilities, although I would very much prefer to use JNA for calling native DLL functions rather than using JNI.

Comment: There is also COM4J I believe: https://com4j.java.net/

Comment: I know of com4j, it does not seem to be updated recently so while on my list of potential ways of using COM, it is down the list. Also I question whether I will be able to get a suitable poiter to the COM objects for then passing on to a standard DLL function call.

Comment: I have looked at what is in the source code repository of JNA, seems like there is a MSOffice demo example in the contrib directory which I think will give me enough at least to get started with the COM support of JNA and as I mentioned I believe this should then allow taking a COM pointer and sending it to a function in a native DLL. I have not yet tested whether this passing a pointer will work, if it does then I will make that an answer for this.